# Resources for learning to deal with audio in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I'm not fully sure what I'm looking for so I was hoping to gain some insight. I'm brainstorming an application I want to write, but I've never dealt with this type of project. I was wondering if any of you knew of any resources, both literature and libraries/APIs that could lead me down the path to creating an application that involves the playback of audio, visualization of audio (like displaying the waveform with a scrolling position), setting playback points, maybe some effects like fade in and out, maybe even beat mapping; all in .net

For example, an application that displays a waveform and has a position indicator that moves with playback. It allows you to visually set multiple start and stop points, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is a good library, but the documentation of how to use it is kinda vague and it doesn't really teach you anything about working with audio files. There is some custom stuff i want to do that isn't included with the library (at least not on the surface), so I'm going to need to actually learn this stuff. What I'm looking for is some sort of primer for that.